# how to put alias inside join statement

Tags: mysql, left-join

hi I want to put an alias in my join statement.

my code is:

```
SELECT distinct id_no, '' as picture, concat(lastname, IF(LENGTH(firstname) > 0 OR LENGTH(middlename) > 0, ', ', ''), concat(IF(p.degree = 5, 'Dr. ', IF(p.degree = 6, 'Dr. ', IF(p.degree = 28, 'Dr. ', '')))), firstname, IF(LENGTH(middlename) > 0, CONCAT(' ', middlename), '')) as name, tp.profession, '' as cv, e.entry_date, e.termination_date 
FROM (bims_people as p)

LEFT JOIN bims_people_education as bpe ON bpe.people_id = p.id_no 

LEFT JOIN tcms_profession as tp ON tp.profession_id = bpe.profession 

LEFT JOIN (select * from bims_people_employment_contract_data order by termination_date DESC) e ON e.people_id = p.id_no 

WHERE p.marked = 0 AND p.id_no > 1 GROUP BY p.id_no ORDER BY lastname ASC LIMIT 100, 50 ;
```

and I want it this way:

```
SELECT distinct id_no, '' as picture, concat(lastname, IF(LENGTH(firstname) > 0 OR LENGTH(middlename) > 0, ', ', ''), concat(IF(p.degree = 5, 'Dr. ', IF(p.degree = 6, 'Dr. ', IF(p.degree = 28, 'Dr. ', '')))), firstname, IF(LENGTH(middlename) > 0, CONCAT(' ', middlename), '')) as name, tp.profession, '' as cv, e.entry_date, e.termination_date 
FROM (bims_people as p)

LEFT JOIN bims_people_education as bpe ON bpe.people_id = p.id_no 

LEFT JOIN tcms_profession as tp ON tp.profession_id = bpe.profession 

LEFT JOIN (select * from bims_people_employment_contract_data **where people_id = p.id_no** order by termination_date DESC limit 1) e ON e.people_id = p.id_no 

WHERE p.marked = 0 AND p.id_no > 1 GROUP BY p.id_no ORDER BY lastname ASC LIMIT 100, 50 ;
```

i keeps telling me that p.id_no is unknown;

Comment: You cannot correlate the subquery like that.  I think you'll need to establish a row number per group (mysql can use user-defined-variables for this) and then filter on rn = 1.

Comment: I think you have some syntax issues;

'SELECT DISTINCT id_no, '' AS picture'

Shouldn't it be 'SELECT DISTINCT id_no AS picture'

Comment: @jas -- There isn't anything wrong with the syntax as is -- it just selects 2 different columns, one column for `id_no`, and one for `picture`.  The `picture` column would just be blank for all rows.

Comment: select * from bims_people_employment_contract_data where people_id = p.id_no ................check this there is no alias for people_id in where condition

Comment: Please read about [mcve]s and give one. Please show (*cut and paste*) your declarations, the query you ran, the error message(s), and your DBMS/SQL.

Comment: What do you expect `LEFT JOIN (select * from bims_people_employment_contract_data
        where people_id = p.id_no
        order by termination_date DESC limit 1) e
    ON e.people_id = p.id_no` (illegally using `p.id_no`)

to do?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> LEFT JOIN (select * from bims_people_employment_contract_data
>     where people_id = p.id_no
>     order by termination_date DESC limit 1) e
> ON e.people_id = p.id_no
> ```

You cannot use a table's alias (correlation name) to define another table to JOIN to it. After you have given two tables & aliases to JOIN, ON or WHERE can use the alias in conditions.

From MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual [14.2.10.8 Subqueries in the FROM Clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/from-clause-subqueries.html)
:

> Subqueries in the FROM clause cannot be correlated subqueries, unless used within the ON clause of a JOIN operation.

(What do you expect the quoted OUTER JOIN to do? Since `p.id_no` doesn't appear in an ON or WHERE, there's no particular row of a table p that it could be the `id_no` value of.)

Maybe you want:

```
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM bims_people_employment_contract_data
    WHERE (people_id, termination_date) IN
        (SELECT people_id, MAX(termination_date) AS termination_date
        FROM bims_people_employment_contract_data
        GROUP BY people_id)
    ) e
ON e.people_id = p.id_no
```